# MYSQL Web Client (Like PHPMYADMIN) without configuration in PHP.ini

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql, web-client

Is there any web client for MySQL which don't need any configration with PHP.ini
I don't have access to Server Configuration File and want any web client like PHPMYADMIN which don't need to modify PHP.INI

Comment: Have you tried MySQL Workbench?

Comment: I need it in web, not in exe windows

Comment: What is it you need to modify in the php.ini for running phpmyamdin? That's certainly not a given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/). It's a single PHP file.